# `sort` disregards question mark

Tags: sort, gnu

I need to sort a file based on names in the first column. Some of the names end in a question mark. `sort` persistently ignores this question mark during sorting:

```
sort -k 1 -t , <<TEST
a?,1
a,2
b?,2
b,1
TEST
```

```
a?,1
a,2
b,1
b?,2
```

I don’t really care about how `sort` orders the question mark, if it only did it *consistently*. But it doesn’t, it seems to consider the second column instead, *even* if I tell `sort` explicitly only to use the first column as key.

Version info:

```
$ sort --version
sort (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Packaged by Gentoo (8.22 (p1.0))
```

Incidentally, on OS X 10.9 (where `sort` identifies itself as “sort (GNU coreutils) 5.93”), the above works as expected for me.

Comment: @mtmiller Oh, that makes sense, but unfortunately neither setting `LC_COLLATE` nor setting `LANG` made a difference, and the Linux and OS X system I’m running this on have the same settings anyway.

Comment: Hmm, `cat | LC_COLLATE=C sort -k 1 -t , <<TEST` with your example input sorts correctly for me.

Comment: @mtmiller EDIT: duh. Yes. That solves it.

Comment: (Which leaves the last question: does OS X, or sort 5.93, disregard the locale setting?)

Comment: It's likely OS X or your shell environment. I have a GNU sort 5.97 that respects locale. Does your working environment even have a locale setting in OS X?

Comment: `sort -k1` sorts on the part of the line that starts at the first field and ends at the end of the line. Use `-k1,1` to sort on the first field only.

Comment: That's not a duplicate as there are two things at play here.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas yes, there are two things at play here, but the original question was asking about the inconsistent ordering of the first fields `x` vs `x?`, which really is about locale and not about the `-k` option.

Comment: @mtmiller, no `x` always sorts before `x?`. It's `x?,1` that sorts before `x,2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LC_ALL=C` seems to give the correct results for me on sort 8.21.

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort -k1,1 -t , sample.txt     
a,2
a?,1
b,1
b?,2
```

Or as you've written it:

```
$ cat | LC_ALL=C sort -k1,1 -t , <<TEST
a?,1
a,2
b?,2
b,1
TEST
a,2
a?,1
b,1
b?,2
```

Incidentally you don't need the `cat`:

```
$ LC_ALL=C sort -k1,1 -t , <<TEST
a?,1
a,2
b?,2
b,1
TEST
a,2
a?,1
b,1
b?,2
```

`LC_COLLATE=C` works for me as well.

#### On the use of `sort -k1` vs. `sort -k1,1`

The above examples all use a modified version of your `sort` command to use `-k1,1` instead of just `-k 1` since this will lead to sorting problems with other special characters such as `%`.

*with just `-k1`*:

```
$ printf '%s\n' a a%,foo a,bar | LC_ALL=C sort -t, -k1    
a
a%,foo
a,bar
```

*with `-k1,1`*:

```
$ printf '%s\n' a a%,foo a,bar | LC_ALL=C sort -t, -k1,1
a
a,bar
a%,foo
```

Comment: `-k1` is redundant as `sort` sorts by default starting from the beginning of the line. You probably want `LC_ALL=C sort -t, -k1,1` as otherwise `a%,b` would sort _before_ `a,b`. Try `printf '%s\n' a a%,foo a,bar | LC_ALL=C sort -t, -k1`

Comment: The abuse of `cat` is even more puzzling as I’m normally the one telling people not to use it redundantly.

Comment: Note also the --debug option to sort to show what's actually being compared. Very useful given the complexities involved.